# Given a direction vector $w$ and some angle $\theta$, then what does $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)}w$ do?

Tags: trigonometry

Given a direction vector $w$ ($w$ refers to the $w$ in $u,v,w,$ however it's not necessarily perpendicular to $u,v$) and some angle $\theta$, then what does $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} w$ do?

I saw this appear in the context of ray-tracing:

[image]

I also found a description where

$$\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)= \text{yres}\cdot \frac{\text{pixel height}} 2$$

which I read that by taking $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} w$ one cancels out the $y$ component (of screen resolution?)? And then gets $2w$ without $y$-component back?

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/3273/5c4af85b6c0ae94c867caeb68b2a1f7182f0.pdf

So does that mean that one makes $w$ (as given in the notes above) point directly perpendicular relative to the screen plane? When it used to be angled?

Comment: the expression $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} v$ simply represents a multiple of vector v

Comment: @gimusi Yeah but what for and why is that the scale factor?

Comment: Iìve added an answer about that

Comment: I've updated the answer after reading the material. Why are you referring to $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} v$? I cannot find that expression in the slide notes.

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $\theta \neq k\pi$

- $k=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} $

is a real number and the product

- $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} \vec v=k \vec v$

represent the product of a vector by a scalar that is a scaled vector with the same direction of $\vec v$.

Reading your material it seems that $\vec v$ is a coordinate vector (in vertical direction) and the full expression

- $Eye+\vec w-(xres/2)\cdot PixelWidth\cdot \vec u +(yres/2)\cdot PixelHeight\cdot \vec v$

simply refer to the coordinates of the upper left corner of the screen.

In that context the product

- $(yres/2)\cdot PixelHeight\cdot \vec v= \tan(\theta_y /2)\cdot \vec v$

is the vertical component of the corner with respect to the center of the screen.

Comment: This does not explain why is the scaling done.

Comment: It is a basic properties of vectors. Do you have some doubts about that?

Comment: $kv \not = v$ so why would one want to use something scaled by some angle derived $\arctan$? Usually when one sees these kinds of scalars, then the idea is to perhaps normalize them "relative to the angle" or something. Or that it follows some sort of symmetry, which is not present in the non-multiplied vector.

Comment: Why in the OP are you referring also to $\arctan(\theta/2)$? Note that in general $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta/2)} \neq \arctan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: @mavavilj Maybe you should add some more detail and context about the question presenting the motivation for that OP.